# Searching title of an old sci-fi B movie with carnivorous aquatic plants

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies, plants

I'm looking for the title of an old sci-fi B movie (B/W). It is about a tourist cruise, perhaps an ocean liner, that gets lost in a kind of fog. When the fog clears, they realize that the ship is trapped between some giant spiny algae that do not allow them to move the ship. From a nearby island, men approach using balloons tied to their backs and large snowshoes to walk above the plants, which can attack and devour humans. The passengers of the ship are taken by these men to their regent, who governs a feudal state and who can condemn them to death, throwing them into a pit near the throne where the carnivorous plants are.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Answer (score 9):

[The Lost Continent (1968)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063240/?ref_=tt_urv)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Continent_(1968_film))

> The film sees the crew and passengers of the dilapidated tramp steamer Corita heading from Freetown to Caracas. While the passengers all have their own reasons for getting out of Africa, the captain of the ship is also eager to leave, as he is smuggling a dangerous explosive cargo. Whilst en route to South America the ship is holed and eventually what's left of the crew and passengers find themselves marooned in a mist-enshrouded Sargasso Sea surrounded by killer seaweed, murderous crustaceans and previously marooned descendants of Spanish Conquistadores and pirates.
>
> ..
>
> The following morning, Lansen's lifeboat finds itself adrift in a morass of large, **sentient and carnivorous seaweed**, which kills the cook.
>
> ..
>
> Sarah, a mysterious native girl from a nearby island, suddenly appears, walking on the morass of seaweed, **prevented from sinking by air buoyancy balloons** attached to her shoulders and odd pads attached to her feet.

Found via search - "scifi movie cruise carnivorous sargasso"